# Display taxonomies as excerpts

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, acfpro

I created recipe posts and taxonomies using ACF Pro and placed the code in my child theme single.php. I have styled my recipe posts and everything is great, but I would like to display all of my recipes as excerpts in a page so they can be categorized.

What do I need to do to get all of my recipes to display excerpts on a page? I think I need to modify the archive.php file, but I am not sure.

Comment: Is your recipe content in the normal WordPress body, in an ACF field, or in multiple fields. If the first you can look into `get_the_excerpt` but read the notes about loop usage. If the second check out `wp_trim_excerpt`. If the third, get all the fields, merge into a simple text block and use the second method.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to get the excerpt and works good with my theme.

```
add_filter(
    'generateblocks_dynamic_content_output',
    function ($content, $attributes, $block) {
        if (
            !is_admin()
            && !empty($attributes['className'])
            && strpos($attributes['className'], 'trim-custom-description') !== false
        ) {
            $stripHTML = strip_tags($content);
            $content = substr($stripHTML, 0, 92) . ' ...'; 
        }
        return $content;
    },
    10,
    3
);
```